# I want to study $\sqrt[n]{n}$ and its behavior.

Tags: analysis

As I was studying some limit problems, I came across

$$\sqrt[n]{n}$$

and astoundingly found out that the graph of this has a maximum when $n = e$.

I thought there is no way that this is not a famous fact and I am very interested in it. I looked up some words such as "nth roots" or "rational exponents" but I haven't found this fact right away.

Can someone guide me to a link or tell me at least what this expression goes by in order to do a little bit of researching ?

Comment: $\sqrt[n]{n}=n^{(1/n)}=e^{\ln(n)/n}$. Show that ${\ln(n)/n}$ maxes out at $n=e$, and then $e^{\ln(n)/n}$ maxes out at $e$ too.

Comment: If you were studying limits problems couldn't it be that $\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ and thus it can **not** be $\,n=e\,$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Derivatives are part of limits, right ?

Comment: Well, derivatives **are** limits, @hyg17 , yet when we use the letter $\,n\,$ we *usually* refer to discrete limits: sequences indexed by the natural numbers. Of course, it may be you decided to use that letter as continuous variable...]

Comment: As a general rule, mathematicians use $n$ to represent natural numbers and integers. Not a law or anything, but it is confusing if you write $\sqrt[n]{n}$ and not explicitly say what your domain is for $n$ - almost all mathematicians will read it as the natural numbers. (If you had written $\sqrt[x]{x}$, most mathematicians will read it as positive real numbers...)

Comment: By the way, can anyone tell me where I can find some facts about $\sqrt[x]{x}$ ?

Comment: Awfully snotty for someone asking people to help you out for free.

Comment: To better understand the phenomenon you are observing, pretend you did not know about the number $e$. Try to work out the derivative without using $e$ or the base $e$ logarithm. How have you defined the number $e$? One common way is by the limit $e = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1 +x^{-1})^x$. I suspect that the limit defining $f'(x) = 0$ where $f(x) = x^{1/x}$ is equivalent to the above definition of $e$ by some algebraic manipulation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: You know what, I noticed how I sounded like when you commented about what I said. I deeply apologize. My ignorance lead to a horrible comment and I'm sorry for what I did. Thank you for teaching me something I did not know, and I will not forget this thanks to you. Again, I'm truly sorry for how I reacted. I will delete my comment as it is an eyesore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply derive to find the maximum, but first note that
$$\sqrt[n]{n} =n^{1/n}=\exp(\log(n^{1/n}))$$
This should explain the connection with $e$. In more detail:
$$\frac{dn^{1/n}}{dn}=n^{1/n}\frac{1-\log n}{n^2}$$
So the derivative is only zero when $\log n = 1 \to \ n=e$.

Comment: Where would I be able to find more facts about this expression ?

Comment: @hyg17 There aren't a lot of facts to be found. What specifically do you want to know?

Comment: @hyg17 - you'll have to specify what else you want to know..

Comment: It would have been best if I could know what this expression is known for. Because I am more interested in what application to mankind it would be used as and its practicality. Mathematically its also fascinating, but I would only be able to find out a very limited amount since my knowledge is not as deep as most people who uses this site.

Comment: @hyg17 - In short, AWAIK this expression is not known for anything practical and is not otherwise useful in mathematics. It's just another function. Hope this answers your question.